# TypeError: $(...).lightBox is not a function in Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am new in React testing in jest. I'm getting an error when I try to simulate 'click' event. I tried many solutions but not able to resolve this issue. My implementation is like this:

```
<span 
    className="add" 
    ref={(targetNode)=>
    {this.addEmploymentBtn=targetNode;}} 
    onClick={this.initDrawerCall}>ADD JOB PROFILE
</span>


initDrawerCall = () => {
    this.state.addEmploymentInstance = $(this.addEmploymentBtn).lightBox({
      // something here...  
    });
}
```

My Test Case :

```
it('opens a LightBox', () => {
    wrapper.find('.add').simulate('click');
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.find(OnlineProfilesContainer).length).toEqual(1);
});
```

Console Error :

```
TypeError: $(...).lightBox is not a function

  14 |
  15 |     initDrawerCall = () => {
> 16 |         this.state.addOnlineProfileInstance = $(this.addOnlineProfileBtn).lightBox({
     |                                                                           ^
  17 |             model: $(this.addOnlineProfileCont),
  18 |             dimens: { width: "50%"},
  19 |             open: { anim: "flipOpen",minTop:100,
```

Answer (score 0):

you can mock the jQuery library inside your jest if it is not some thing you want to test. you can do it by adding file `jestSetup.js` and add this code inside:

```
global.$ = () => ({
  lightBox: jest.fn()
})
```

and inside your `jest.config.js` add path to this file like this:

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest/jestSetup.js'],
```